# Any way to access Console.log() Output from QTP?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

In QTP, is there a way to see what the Javascript application is writing to the browser's debugger console?  That is, the warnings and errors that are written via a JS call to window.console.log().

This output does not seem to be flowing directly to the QTP output window.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `console` output in the browser is not supported by UFT, however you can use UFT's [`EmbedScript`](https://munibala.wordpress.com/tag/embedscript/) function in order to send console messages to wherever you want.

JS Example:

```
// OverrideConsole.js
if (window.console) {
    console.error = function(msg) {
        // send error message to your output file
    }
    // ditto for any other functions you want
}
```

Then use this line in the beginning of the test:

```
Browser("B").EmbedScriptFromFile("C:\OverrideConsole.js")
```